# Pandas: Comparing 2 dataframes without iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering I have 2 dataframes as shown below (`DF1` and `DF2`), I need to compare DF2 with DF1 such that I can identify all the Matching, Different, Missing values for all the columns in DF2 that match columns in DF1 (Col1, Col2 & Col3 in this case) for rows with same EID value (A, B, C & D). I do not wish to iterate on each row of a dataframe as it can be time-consuming.
Note: There can around 70 - 100 columns. This is just a sample dataframe I am using.

`DF1`

```
    EID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0   A   a1   b1   c1   d1
1   B   a2   b2   c2   d2
2   C   None b3   c3   d3
3   D   a4   b4   c4   d4
4   G   a5   b5   c5   d5
```

`DF2`

```
    EID Col1 Col2 Col3
0   A   a1   b1   c1
1   B   a2   b2   c9
2   C   a3   b3   c3
3   D   a4   b4   None
```

`Expected output dataframe`

```
    EID Col1 Col2 Col3 New_Col
0   A   a1   b1   c1   Match
1   B   a2   b2   c2   Different
2   C   None b3   c3   Missing in DF1
3   D   a4   b4   c4   Missing in DF2
```

Comment: May I ask how if you have a `None` in your row data, it will be considered as Missing?

Comment: Yes, None is missing data

Comment: @ShashankShekher Are the values in Col1...ColX of the same data type? Do we know the data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to filter df1 based on df2.

```
new_df = df1.loc[df1['EID'].isin(df2['EID']), df2.columns]

  EID  Col1 Col2 Col3
0   A    a1   b1   c1
1   B    a2   b2   c2
2   C  None   b3   c3
3   D    a4   b4   c4
```

Next, since you have a big dataframe to compare, you can change both the `new_df` and `df2` to numpy arrays.

```
array1 = new_df.to_numpy()
array2 = df2.to_numpy()
```

Now you can compare it row-wise using `np.where`

```
new_df['New Col'] = np.where((array1 == array2).all(axis=1),'Match', 'Different')

  EID  Col1 Col2 Col3    New Col
0   A    a1   b1   c1      Match
1   B    a2   b2   c2  Different
2   C  None   b3   c3  Different
3   D    a4   b4   c4  Different
```

Finally, to convert the row with `None` value, you can use `df.loc` and `df.isnull`

```
new_df.loc[new_df.isnull().any(axis=1), ['New Col']] = 'Missing in DF1'
new_df.loc[df2.isnull().any(axis=1), ['New Col']] = 'Missing in DF2'

  EID  Col1 Col2 Col3         New Col
0   A    a1   b1   c1           Match
1   B    a2   b2   c2       Different
2   C  None   b3   c3  Missing in DF1
3   D    a4   b4   c4  Missing in DF2
```

Comment: I would consider setting **`EID`** as an index and using **`pandas.DataFrame.align()`** method in the first block.

Comment: @BorisSilantev That's another way to do so :) You can post it as a solution. I'm not sure which method OP is desiring for

Comment: Is the `to_numpy` really necessary? From what I know, `np.where` should automatically take the underlying numpy object of the DataFrame and work just fine.

Comment: The whole logic could be put more concisely if you used `np.select` instead of `np.where` This would remove the need to edit the column after creating it.

Comment: @miriess I understand where you are coming, but the OP wants the process to be fast, that's why I'm not sure if using no.where on dataframe directly will be efficient enough or not.

Comment: Interesting point... I always figured that the numpy array is the baseline element of a Dataframe and conversion is basically free, but found no proof of it with a quick repo search. I might just go and try to time it.

Comment: Interesting method. Has the advantage of simplicity for people like me who are more comfortable with numpy. Not the fastest tho. Way faster, obviously, than direct iteration the OP wants to avoid (431000 ms), or apply based method (275000 ms). This method took 1872 ms on the same benchmark. So, not at all the same territory as direct iterations. Yet, @Lance method beats this, taking only 257 ms

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that `"Match"`, `"Different"`, `"Missing in DF1"`, and `"Missing in DF1"` are not mutually exclusive.
You can have some values missing in DF1, but also missing in DF2.

However, based on your post, the priority seems to be:
`"Match" > "Missing in DF1" > "Missing in DF2"  > "Different"`.

Also, it seems like you're using `EID` as an index, so it makes more sense to use it as the dataframe index. You can call `.reset_index()` if you want it as a column.

The approach is to use the equality operator / null check element-wise, then call `.all` and `.any` across columns.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def compare_dfs(df1, df2):
    # output dataframe has df2 dimensions, but df1 values
    result = df1.reindex(index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns)

    # check if values match; note that None == None, but np.nan != np.nan
    eq_check = (result == df2).all(axis=1)
    # null values are understood to be "missing"
    #   change the condition otherwise
    null_check1 = result.isnull().any(axis=1)
    null_check2 = df2.isnull().any(axis=1)

    # create New_Col based on inferred priority
    result.loc[:, "New_Col"] = None
    result.loc[result["New_Col"].isnull() & eq_check, "New_Col"] = "Match"
    result.loc[
        result["New_Col"].isnull() & null_check1, "New_Col"
    ] = "Missing in DF1"
    result.loc[
        result["New_Col"].isnull() & null_check2, "New_Col"
    ] = "Missing in DF2"
    result["New_Col"].fillna("Different", inplace=True)

    return result
```

You can test your inputs in a jupyter notebook:

```
import itertools as it

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(["".join(i) for i in it.product(list("abcd"), list("12345"))])
    .reshape((4, 5))
    .T,
    index=pd.Index(list("ABCDG"), name="EID"),
    columns=[f"Col{i + 1}" for i in range(4)],
)

df1.loc["C", "Col1"] = None

df2 = df1.iloc[:4, :3].copy()
df2.loc["B", "Col3"] = "c9"
df2.loc["D", "Col3"] = None

display(df1)
display(df2)

display(compare_dfs(df1, df2))
```

Which should give these results:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
EID             
A   a1  b1  c1  d1
B   a2  b2  c2  d2
C   None    b3  c3  d3
D   a4  b4  c4  d4
G   a5  b5  c5  d5
Col1    Col2    Col3
EID         
A   a1  b1  c1
B   a2  b2  c9
C   None    b3  c3
D   a4  b4  None
Col1    Col2    Col3    New_Col
EID             
A   a1  b1  c1  Match
B   a2  b2  c2  Different
C   None    b3  c3  Missing in DF1
D   a4  b4  c4  Missing in DF2
```

On my i7 6600U local machine, the function takes ~1 sec for a dataset with 1 million rows, 80 columns.

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

test_size = (1_000_000, 100)

df1 = (
    pd.DataFrame(rng.random(test_size))
    .rename_axis(index="EID")
    .rename(columns=lambda x: f"Col{x + 1}")
)

df2 = df1.sample(frac=0.8, axis=1)

# add difference
df2 += rng.random(df2.shape) > 0.9

# add nulls
df1[rng.random(df1.shape) > 0.99] = np.nan
df2[rng.random(df2.shape) > 0.99] = np.nan

%timeit compare_dfs(df1, df2)
```

`953 ms ± 199 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: That one is the fastest so far, in my benchmark: 257 ms

Answer (score 1):

Underneath it all, you're still going to be doing iterations. However, what you can do is merge the two columns on the EID, perform and outer join, and then use an apply function to generate your new_col.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='EID', how='outer', lsuffix='df1_', rsuffix='df2_')
df3['comparison'] = df3.apply(lambda x: comparison_function(x), axis=1)
# your comparison_function will have your checks that result in missing in df1, df2, etc
```

You can then use

Comment: You meant "prefix" I guess.

Comment: Plus, why ```lambda x: cf(x)``` rather than just ```cf``` ?

Comment: And finally, apply is the same evil as iterating, or almost so. It calls a python function on each line. I am having fun benchmarking solutions from different contributors here. So far, the worst one takes 1872 ms, the best one 257 ms. Yours took 275395 ms. Sure, faster than a direct iteration on values, but in the same territory (431462 ms).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#1. 
DF1 = DF1.drop('Col4', axis=1)
df= pd.merge(DF2, DF1.loc[df['EID'].ne('G')], on=['Col1','Col2', 'Col3', 'EID'], how='left', indicator='New Col')
df['New Col'] = np.where(df['New Col'] == 'left_only', "Missing in DF1", df['New Col'])

df = df.merge(pd.merge(DF2.loc[:, ['EID','Col1','Col2']], DF1.loc[DF1['EID'].ne('G'), [ 'EID', 'Col1','Col2',]], on=['EID', 'Col1','Col2', ], how='left', indicator='col1_col2'), on=['EID','Col1','Col2'], how='left')
df = df.merge(pd.merge(DF2.loc[:, ['EID','Col2','Col3']], DF1.loc[DF1['EID'].ne('G'), [ 'EID', 'Col2','Col3',]], on=['EID', 'Col2','Col3', ], how='left', indicator='col2_col3'), on=['EID','Col2','Col3'], how='left')
df = df.merge(pd.merge(DF2.loc[:, ['EID','Col1','Col3']], DF1.loc[DF1['EID'].ne('G'), [ 'EID', 'Col1','Col3',]], on=['EID', 'Col1','Col3', ], how='left', indicator='col1_col3'), on=['EID','Col1','Col3'], how='left')

a1 = df['New Col'].eq('both') #match
a2 = df['col1_col2'].eq('both') & df['New Col'].eq('Missing in DF1') #same by Col1 & Col2 --> Different
a3 = df['col2_col3'].eq('both') & df['New Col'].eq('Missing in DF1') #same by Col2 & Col3 --> Different
a4 = df['col1_col3'].eq('both') & df['New Col'].eq('Missing in DF1') #same by Col1 & Col3 --> Different
df['New Col'] = np.select([a1, a2, a3, a4], ['match', 'Different/ same Col1 & Col2', 'Different/ same Col2 & Col3', 'Different/ same Col1 & Col3'], df['New Col'])
df = df.drop(columns=['col1_col2', 'col2_col3', 'col1_col3'])

    EID Col1    Col2    Col3    New Col
0   A   a1      b1      c1      match
1   B   a2      b2      c9      Different/ same Col1 & Col2
2   C   a3      b3      c3      Different/ same Col2 & Col3
3   D   a4      b4      None    Different/ same Col1 & Col2
```

or

```
#2.
DF1 = DF1.drop('Col4', axis=1)
df= pd.merge(DF2, DF1.loc[df['EID'].ne('G')], on=['Col1','Col2', 'Col3', 'EID'], how='left', indicator='New Col')
df['New Col'] = np.where(df['New Col'] == 'left_only', "Missing in DF1", df['New Col'])

df = df.merge(pd.merge(DF2.loc[:, ['EID','Col1','Col2']], DF1.loc[DF1['EID'].ne('G'), [ 'EID', 'Col1','Col2',]], on=['EID', 'Col1','Col2', ], how='left', indicator='col1_col2'), on=['EID','Col1','Col2'], how='left')

a1 = df['New Col'].eq('both') #match
a2 = df['col1_col2'].eq('both') & df['New Col'].eq('Missing in DF1') #Different

df['New Col'] = np.select([a1, a2], ['match', 'Different'], df['New Col'])

df = df.drop(columns=['col1_col2'])

    EID Col1    Col2    Col3    New Col
0   A   a1      b1      c1      match
1   B   a2      b2      c9      Different
2   C   a3      b3      c3      Missing in DF1
3   D   a4      b4      None    Different
```

- **Note1: **no iteration****
- Note2: goal of this solution: compare DF2 with DF1 such that you can identify all the Matching, Different, Missing values for `all the columns in DF2 that match columns in DF1` (Col1, Col2 & Col3 in this case) for rows with same EID value (A, B, C & D)

Comment: Both these solutions might not be effective as I can have millions of EIDs and hundreds of columns. Can you please provide something in generic?

Comment: what do you mean ? this is based on your question I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_df1 = df1[df2.columns] # to compare the only available columns in df2
joined_df = df2.merge(temp_df1, on='EID') # default indicator is '_x' for left table (df2) and '_y' for right table (df1)

# getting the columns that need to be compared 
cols = list(df2.columns)
cols.remove('EID')
cols_left = [i+'_x' for i in cols]
cols_right =  [i+'_y' for i in cols]

# getting back the table
temp_df2 = joined_df[cols_left]
temp_df2.columns=cols
temp_df1 = joined_df[cols_right]
temp_df1.columns=cols

output_df = joined_df[['EID']].copy()
output_df[cols] = temp_df1

filt = (temp_df2 == temp_df1).all(axis=1)
output_df.loc[filt, 'New_Col'] = 'Match'
output_df.loc[~filt, 'New_Col'] = 'Different'
output_df.loc[temp_df2.isna().any(axis=1), 'New_Col'] = 'Missing in df2' # getting missing values in df2
output_df.loc[temp_df1.isna().any(axis=1), 'New_Col'] = 'Missing in df1' # getting missing values in df1

output_df

   EID  Col1 Col2 Col3  New_Col
0   A    a1   b1    c1  Match
1   B    a2   b2    c2  Different
2   C    NaN  b3    c3  Missing in df1
3   D    a4   b4    c4  Missing in df2
```

Comment: 1442 ms in my benchmark. Better than Kevin's 1872 ms, but yet, it does not beat Lances's 257 ms.